# How to call a function in Chai assertion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

Given:

```
let foo = {
    alwaysTrue: () => { return true }
}
```

I want to assert that foo.alwaysTrue is true with an elegant syntax similar to:

`expect(foo).to.be.alwaysTrue();`

Is this possible in chai?

Comment: what is always true? foo or the function call? To me, that syntax is a bit misleading...

Comment: I'm looking for a syntax similar to RSpec's predicate matchers: http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/rspec-predicate-matchers

Answer (score 0):

If your asking how to call the property as a function...

> expect(foo.alwaysTrue()).to.be.alwaysTrue();

If you want to create a custom chai assertion/ helper function, [check this out](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/helpers/)

It works by adding new functions into chai's prototype chain.